# Firebase database query by key value

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have JSON like this.

```
   livefeeds= {
        "-KTn8pbqFHBUvgJ1Gwyl" =     {
            category = Alerts;
            text = "Samsung Galaxy Note 7 owners told to turn off device";
            timestamp = 1476179485648;
            "user_id" = V7EFBV6uATf8urLXX9eK4EHhxmG2;
        };
        "-KTn8pbrhHyNzeLh2vOq" =     {
            category = News;
            text = "Chicago Teachers Union, school board reach tentative contract agreement";
            timestamp = 1476179485648;
            "user_id" = V7EFBV6uATf8urLXX9eK4EHhxmG2;
        };
    }
```

I need to make query based on the key `category`.

Ex: If I only want Alerts, it should only retrieve category value equal to "Alerts" data only.

Here is query to retrieve `livefeeds`.

```
  [[self.ref queryOrderedByChild:@"livefeeds"]  observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSLog(@"---> %@",snapshot.value);
  }];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First go till child "livefeeds" and then "queryOrderedByChild" category and use `equal to` child like this way

```
[[[[self.ref child:@"livefeeds"] queryOrderedByChild:@"category"]   
                                   queryEqualToValue:groupId]   
                                    observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.value != [NSNull null]){
        for (NSDictionary *snap in [snapshot.value allValues]) {
             NSLog(@"---> %@",snap);
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Oh Thank you. i don't know how i missed it.. when i tried it i got "Null" result. but now its working,